# Search all of Apple Music with AppleScript?

Tags: macos, applescript, music, automation

So I'm working on a project to convert Spotify to Apple Music playlists and I'm utilizing AppleScript to do so. I was wondering if anyone knows how to search all of Apple Music when utilizing the search function.

```
set myList to {"Bound2", "Malfunction"}


activate application "Music"
tell application "Music"
    make new user playlist with properties {name:"Conversion"}
end tell


tell application "Music"
    repeat with theItem in myList
        set theSearch to (search for theItem)
        add theSearch to playlist "Conversion"
    end repeat
    
end tell
```

This sets up a list of music, creates a blank playlist, then iterates through the list adding each song `theItem` to the blank playlist.

The issue is the `search` function needs a parameter for a place to search through. For example, it needs `Library` to search through the users library. I cannot find a parameter to search through all of Apple Music though. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I like this shortcut since it works on iOS and macOS and you can inspect the API usage before importing it.

- https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/cbdbcde5659b41c2928aec4b42567662

It has a note on who made it and a tutorial on YouTube. I’m not good enough with AppleScript to translate it, though.

[image]

Comment: As a side note, I’m tempted to get an app for this rather than parse url - https://www.macstories.net/reviews/musicbox-review-the-listen-later-music-app-ive-been-waiting-for/